# Actionbar like youtube

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

[image: youtube actionbar]

I have made an actionbar like this which is nested using the child Fragment Manager but i am unable to style it like the red color youtube has done. How do I style the actionbar for nested fragments. Please Help.

Comment: Use the `Toolbar`. You can create it in your `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thanx a lot i'll try that and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example, it uses all the latest libraries and is very easy to understand and copy/reuse for your project

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

[image: Cheesesquare app image]